# Query and CountQuery Concurrently Java Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, asynchronous, concurrency

I have a query that requires pagination and I want to run the query and countQuery at the same time. I also want to get the result in a Page object so I know how many items, total count, nextPage etc. I am not sure if this is possible without some sort of custom implementation.

Lets say I have something like this
`@Query(value="select * from users where tag=tag;" countQuery="select count(*) from (select * from users where tag=tag) as qcount") Page<User> getUsersWithTag(Tag tag, Pageable pagination)` 
Is it possible to run both the count and query at the same time and get a Page result? I am thinking about using springs `@Async` annotation, I guess these methods would have to be split apart.

I have tried just adding `@Async` onto the method but that seems to actually hurt the performance. I am aware I may need to use `Future` or `CompletableFuture` to do this, just not sure how I can get the Page information together.

**Update:**
I have found somewhat of a hacky soltuion but basically using java Futures and Spring Async I have done this.

```
@Query(value="select * from users;")
@Async 
Future<Page<User>> getUsersWithTag(Tag tag, Pageable pagination)

@Query(value="select count(*) from (select * from users where tag=tag) as qcount")
@Async
Future<Long> getUsersWithTagCount(Tag tag, Pageable pagination)

List<User> users = getUsersWithTag(tag, pageable).get();
long count = getUsersWithTagCount(tag, pageable).get();
Page<User> = new PageImpl<>(users, pageable, count);
```

Comment: The ask seems to be to run these two separate queries/statements concurrently instead of one after the other. Doing so over multiple process and threads could quickly hurt an application performance as it requires multiple connections to be obtained and held to run the queries. You can quickly run out of connections with that level of concurrency, and will find overhead of getting and releasing connections from the pool grow. If you must split it, you are better off having the app make separate calls: count shouldn't change frequently, so why bother querying it on every page access?

Comment: @Chris Actually the example isn't really a good one, queries in my application vary often and have different counts frequently, the count is needed for pagination. Your point is valid this may hurt the overall performance of the app, but I need faster querying performance. I have found a somewhat hacky solution that I will share below. I am not worried about the app overusing cpu and memory as this is in a cluster that monitors cpu/memory and provisions more instances based on demand

Comment: Cluster cpu wasn’t my concern. dB resources like physical connections, is what I was warning against, and the extra overhead to the dataSource itself. As for caching- I mean with the same pagination query. Most uses of pagination I’ve seen are UIs, and getting the count each time with every page to display the same results while a user goes through pages is unnecessary overhead

Answer (score 0):

You already have this information **in your paged** result set

```
Page<User> getAllUsers(Pageable pagination)
```

You return `Page<User>` and there you have available the method `getTotalElements()` which should return to you the total number of elements contained in all pages.

Also

```
@Query(value="select * from users;" countQuery="select count(*) from (select * from users) as qcount") Page<User> getAllUsers(Pageable pagination)
```

The part `countQuery="select count(*) from (select * from users) as qcount"` is redundant as spring will by default create and use the same query by itself, only because you use Pagination in your declared method.

Answer (score 0):

With org.springframework.data.domain.Page you already have :

{
"totalElements": 0,
"totalPages": 0,
"size": 0,
"content": [
{...

See [Page doc](https://%7B%20%20%20%22totalElements%22:%200,%20%20%20%22totalPages%22:%200,%20%20%20%22size%22:%200,%20%20%20%22content%22:%20%5B%20%20%20%20%20%7B) for more details.